# android test fixtures

Tags: android, testing

I am working on an android app and I have created a new test project for unit tests. Where's recommended to store the test fixtures (like xml files and the like) and what's the proper way to access it ?

Answer (score 3):

It depends if you really mean *unit test* or *instrumented tests* (like using espresso and stuff)...

## Unit tests:

1. Put your fixtures in `src/test/resources` (so e.g. `src/test/resources/fixture.json`)
2. Access them from your test classes e.g. using:

```
InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("fixture.json")
```

## Instrumented tests:

1. Put your fixtures in `src/androidTest/assets/` (so e.g. `src/androidTest/assets/fixture.json`)
2. Access them from your test classes e.g. using:

```
InputStream is = InstrumentationRegistry.getContext().getResources().getAssets().open("fixture.json")
```

---

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309424/read-convert-an-inputstream-to-a-string) are some examples of how you can convert `InputStream` to `String`.

[Here's a pretty good post](https://medium.com/@yair.kukielka/android-unit-tests-explained-part-2-a0f1e1413569) describing different cases.

---

P.S. *I know this question is 6+ years old... answering for any future searches.*

Answer (score 2):

After some searching I found there is no **one proper** way to store fixtures in Android (also not so much in java either).

Fixtures are a way to provide easy and consistent data to be passed into test cases. Creating `.java` classes with static methods that return objects is one way to go.

Example:

```
public class Pojos {

    public static List<TaskListItem> taskListItems() {
        return Arrays.asList(
                new TaskListItem("one"),
                new TaskListItem("two"),
                new TaskListItem("three")
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can configure Gradle to read resources from a shared folder, you will be able to share code and resources either in unit test or instrumented test by doing the following.

```
android {
    // ...
    sourceSets {

        final String sharedJavaDir = 'src/sharedTest/java'
        final String sharedResourcesDir = 'src/sharedTest/resources'

        test.java.srcDirs += sharedJavaDir
        test.resources.srcDirs += [sharedResourcesDir]

        androidTest.java.srcDirs += sharedJavaDir
        androidTest.resources.srcDirs += [sharedResourcesDir]

        // ....
    }
    // ...
}
```

Let's imagine that I setup a shared test resource in

```
/app/src/sharedTest/resources/test_fixture_file.txt
```

Kotlin code

In a UnitTest or Instrumented test you can use.

```
val resource: InputStream? = this.javaClass.getResourceAsStream("/test_fixture_file.txt")
```

Comment: This does not work in current Intellij/AndroidStudio as IntelliJ does not support have the same srcDir folder in two separate modules sourceSet. IntelliJ will give you a warning when opening the dir.